# Determine if two random variables are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X \sim U(-1, 1)$ (continuous uniform distribution between -1 and 1), and $Z = U(0, 1/10)$ and let X and Z be independent. Define $Y=X^2+Z$. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Even if I compute the density of $Y$ I don't think it will help me much since we don't know the joint density. So the only way that I see to proceed is to consider the conditional density, but I am not sure how. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: you get the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ from $\mathbb P\{X\le x,X^2+Z\le y\}$. Then see if this is the product of the individual densities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $U,V\in L^1$ are independent random variables, then $E[U|V]=E[U]$ a.e. So, if $P(E[U|V]\neq E[U])>0$ then $U,V$ are not independent. We have $X,Y \in L^1$. We see $E[Y|X]=X^2+E[Z]=X^2+1/20$ and $E[Y]=1/3+1/20$, and we conclude.